# Compiling any single C code using a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am pretty new to Makefiles, so my question might be silly. It would be the following: Can I pass another argument to `make` so that I can do stuff with this additional argument?
More specifically, if possible, I would want to use this to compile any single C source code into its executable using a Makefile.

For example, if I have two files **foo.c** and **bar.c**, I would want to be able to compile them using the same recipe, therefore doing something similar to `make compile foo.c` or `make compile bar.c` that compiles them into the **foo** or **bar** executables, respectively.

If it is not possible, is there an alternative I can do for simple C programs? It would be useful to save time (not updating the Makefile or not writing `gcc -o name name.c` every time I want to compile a C file I just created).

Thank you in advance for your patience and time.

Comment: It sounds like you want targets?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by targets (sorry for being a newbie...). Are you referring to targets in `targets: dependencies` in any Makefile recipe, or to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with single main file applications, a bash script sounds much simpler, `build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE=$1
BIN=${SOURCE%.c}
if [[ -z "$SOURCE" || ! -s "$SOURCE" ]]; then
    echo "SOURCE is empty"
    exit 1
fi
gcc -o "$BIN" "$SOURCE"
```

and then invoke it like this:

```
./build.sh foo.c
./build.sh bar.c
```

Comment: It should be `[[ -s $SOURCE ]]` to check that the file exists and is non-emptry. (you actually want both, `-z` to ensure `$SOURCE` is not an empty-string, and then `-s` to make sure the file exits and is non-empty) But yes, a single script to compile files is much simpler than writing one makefile for each.

Comment: right, that will be safer, but i'm wondering should it be `-s` or `-f`, the 1st check file and it's size is larger than zero, the 2nd check it's a regular file.

Comment: I'd use `-s` because it includes `-f` and then provides an additional check that the file-size is non-zero. Manpage says `"True if file exists and has a size greater than zero."` (of course `gcc` will just ignore the empty file or throw an error) This just catches the condition before the `gcc` call.

Comment: I mean, you're basically just reinventing make here, so you have to maintain it yourself AND you get less capability.  But if it works for you go for it!

Answer (score 1):

I use the makefile below for this. 'make' or 'make all' compiles each .c (eg eg.c) file in the directory to an executable in the same directory (eg eg). 'make eg' compiles just eg.c to eg . There's nothing special about the compiler flags -- CFLAGS -- or linker flags -- LFLAGS -- they're just what I habitually use.

```
CC  = gcc
CFLAGS  = -std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS  = -lm -lrt

OPATH   = ./
PROGS   += $(patsubst %.c,$(OPATH)%,$(wildcard *.c))


all: $(PROGS)
$(OPATH)% : %.c ; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

clean:  
    \rm -f $(PROGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make has built-in rules that knows how to compile a source file into an executable.

So, you don't even have to write a makefile at all (unless you want to use special compiler options).  This will work:

```
$ ls
bar.c   foo.c

$ make foo
cc -o foo foo.c

$ make bar
cc -o bar bar.c
```

If you want to modify the compiler operations, add a makefile that sets the appropriate built-in variables:

```
$ ls
bar.c   foo.c   Makefile

$ cat Makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O2 -g

$ make foo
gcc -O2 -g -o foo foo.c

$ make bar
gcc -O2 -g -o bar bar.c
```

Comment: how to clear compiled object?

Comment: _how to clear compiled object?_  Sorry but I don't understand the question.

Comment: Is there any short form to remove compiled object instead of `rm -f foo` ?

Comment: If you're asking, is there a built-in function or operator in `make` that can remove a file from the disk then the answer is "no".  You have to write a shell command to remove files (just as you have to write a shell command to create a file).

Answer (score 0):

how about using this:

================== makefile =====================

```
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-ansi -pedantic -Wall

all : clean foo bar

foo : foo.c 
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) foo.c -o foo

bar : bar.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) bar.c -o bar

clean : 
    rm -f *.o *.*~ foo bar
```

====================== end makefile ======================

invoking make as `make` will run the default target (all in this case) removing all intermediate files and output files and then rebuilding foo and bar

invoking make as `make foo` will only run the rule for making foo.

invoking make as `make bar` will only run the rule for making bar.

invoking make as `make clean` will only run the rule for cleaning the project directory -- removing all intermediate and output files.

Comment: I wish to avoid modifying the Makefile after creating a new `.c` file that I want to compile. In other words, if I create a new file `baz.c`, I would like to be able to compile it without adding a Makefile recipe for `baz`. What I would want is a general recipe that works for compiling any `.c` file.

Comment: @benhauer you might want to look at implicit rules (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) and patterns (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules) to do this.  I've never tried this myself - most of my build rules are complicated enough that I always create a custom makefile for the project.